# Struts 2 - How to use package in URL

Tags: struts2, struts2-namespace

I would like to build a dynamic web project like that:

Method: GET | POST | DELETE
API URL: http://example.com/api/

Example:

- I need to get User by executing URL: http://example.com/api/users/user_id/
- To get List of user's albums by executing URL: http://example.com/api/users/user_id/list/
- ...

So can you help me How can I do it by using STRUTS 2.
Please explain something about it if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using namespace attribute of the Package tag in your struts configuration file struts.xml.

Below is the example for doing this.

```
<package name="user" namespace="/User" extends="struts-default">
<action name="Login">
    <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
```

Comment: Thanks fo answering! I used pakage tag but when I use or not, the results are the same. example: user/loginaction & /loginaction

Comment: @JackDuong That's a different issue having to do with the `struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace` default. Try setting it to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [S2 REST plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html).

It sets up everything you need, including result type mapping based on request URL. You might need to do some tweaking for the multi-level bits. If it doesn't work out-of-the-box, you can use the following along with various URL mapping options (including the package namespacing mentioned by Kartik).

Alternatively, you *could* do it manually using a combination of [parameter name matching](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-Parametersinnamespaces) and the JSON plugin (or use whatever result types you need).